# How to change iframe src with click event from another component in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10

I want to change an iframe src when you click the menu bar. My menu bar is in another component, on which you are able to change the language in a dropdown menu. I want to change the iframe src depending on which language was clicked.

Here is my HTML menu wth a function named 'updateSrc()':

```
<nav>

<div class="select-box">
                      <div class="select-box__current" tabindex="1">
                        <div class="select-box__value" (click)="updateSrc(first_url)">
                          <input class="select-box__input" type="radio" id="0" value="1" name="Ben" checked="checked"/>
                          <p class="select-box__input-text">Es</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="select-box__value" (click)="updateSrc(second_url)">
                          <input class="select-box__input" type="radio" id="1" value="2" name="Ben"/>
                          <p class="select-box__input-text">En</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="select-box__value">
                          <input class="select-box__input" type="radio" id="2" value="3" name="Ben"/>
                          <p class="select-box__input-text">It</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="select-box__icon" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_295694.svg" alt="Arrow Icon" aria-hidden="true"/>
                      </div>

                      <ul class="select-box__list">
                        <li>
                          <label class="select-box__option" for="0" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">Es</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <label class="select-box__option" for="1" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">En</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="https://esourcecapital.it/">
                          <label class="select-box__option" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">It</label>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div> 

</nav>
```

Here is my TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  menu:boolean = false;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
    {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  first_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oP20QZxahk";
  second_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q_ZPBqVF0_8";
  current_url: SafeUrl;

  updateSrc(url) {
    this.current_url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }


}
```

And also the iframe I want to change is in another component as I said before:

```
<div class="center">
                            <iframe width="640" height="360" id="frame" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oP20QZxahk" [src]="current_url" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!--                            <div class="pairs">
                                <button md-button (click)="updateSrc(first_url)" id="first" class="top-link">Video en español</button>
                                <button md-button (click)="updateSrc(second_url)" id="second" class="top-link">Video in english</button>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
```

if everything were in the same component it would work, but the menu is in one component and the iframe tag in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) to share data between components.
You need a service:

**Iframe Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IFrameService {

  private srcSubject = new Subject<string>();

  srcObservable$: Observable<string> = this.srcSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
  }

  changeSrc(incomingSrc) {
    this.srcSubject.next(incomingSrc);
  }
}
```

Than you'll inject the service in both components: menu and the iframe component

**Menu TS File**

At the header component file, you will change your changeSrc method, which will call the iFrame Service next method, that will emit the new value for the subject that you created.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  menu:boolean = false;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
              private iframeService: IFrameService)
    {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  first_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oP20QZxahk";
  second_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q_ZPBqVF0_8";
  current_url: SafeUrl;

  updateSrc(url) {
      this.iframeService.changeSrc(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);)
  }
}
```

**IFrame Component File**

At the Iframe component file, you will create a new instance of the service like you did for the header file, but you must instantiate it as a public service, so you will be able to use the service in your template. At your HTML you will subscribe to the observable using the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```html
<div class="center">
  <iframe width="640" height="360" id="frame" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oP20QZxahk" [src]="iframeService.srcObservable | async" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!--<div class="pairs">
      <button md-button (click)="updateSrc(first_url)" id="first" class="top-link">Video en español</button>
      <button md-button (click)="updateSrc(second_url)" id="second" class="top-link">Video in english</button>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

If you still have doubts of how to use subjects and the observable pattern, take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcqZ2RbVZXE&t=7s).

Comment: Ok, I will follow the steps you provide. I think is a very good explanation about it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hello Vítor. I noticed I get a message in the iframe service. In the line where it says:  srcObservable$: Subject<string> = this.srcSubject.asObservable(); I get the following message: Type 'Observable<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subject<string>': observers, closed, isStopped, hasError, and 6 more.
(property) IframeService.srcObservable$: Subject<string>

Comment: I'm sorry I typed as the observable in a subject, when it should be an observable. I edited my answer

Comment: Great!! I will continue now

Comment: Hello Vitor. Following our conversation, I am getting this message from the terminal. In the iframe component html, I have this error: error TS2341: Property 'iframeService' is private and only accessible within class 'IframeComponent'.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, you need to make the service declaration at the constructor public to have access in the template. I'm sorry again about it. Updating the answer

Comment: Woow!! You are incredible, it works!!  Thanks a lot Vitor!!, Can I get in touch with you?

Comment: Hello, One last question.  I have noticed that I must be in the iframe component in order to see the changes made from the header menu; but if I leave to another link of my app and then return to iframe component, the iframe src returns to the first source.

Comment: Of course you can keep in touch. Try to change the subject to the [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject), which is a type of Subject that stores the subject values and when you subscribe again (when leaving and than returning to the page) will emit the last value for it. But keep in mind that to use the BehaviorSubject you need to provide it an initial value.

Comment: Ok, I will follow this advice!

Comment: Hi Vitor  , You may like to help me with this other topic:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267849/how-to-show-a-blog-detail-by-id-in-angular