# How to show a Blog Detail by ID in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, strapi

I want to show a Blog detail by ID in Angular. For that purpose, when you click a button from the Blog main page, the app gets you to the Blog detail page which is 'pagina.component.html' file. I achieved to show all the blogs here, but what I really want is to show a unique blog, depending on the ID blog clicked before in the main page. For that reason, I think I should add a method in my service named 'getItem(idx)' to call just the ID selected and not all the blogs. but I don`t know to do that.

This is my 'pagina.component.html' file which has an ngFor.

```
<article class="articles-blog-post" *ngFor="let data of datas; index as i">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-xs-12">

                        <!-- TEXT ARTICLE -->
                        <div class="articles-header">
                            <time datetime="2016-10-11">{{ data.fecha | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</time>
                            <span class="articles-header-tag-green">Nuevo</span>
                            <span class="articles-header-category">
                                <a href="#" class="green" title="">{{ data.category.name }}</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="articles-content">
                            <h1 class="articles-content-blog-post-title"><a title="Tendencias de Transformacion Digital">{{ data.title }}</a></h1>

                            <div class="foto">
                                <!--<img src="../../../../../assets/img/blog/detalles/foto5-min.jpg" alt="">-->
                                <img src="http://localhost:1337{{ data.image.url }}" alt="foto" width="100%"/>


                            </div>
                            
                            <p>{{ data.content }}</p>

</div>
</div>

</article>
```

And here is my 'pagina.component.ts' file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { StrapiService } from '../../../../services/strapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagina',
  templateUrl: './pagina.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina.component.scss']
})
export class PaginaComponent implements OnInit {

  datas:any=[];
  data:any;
  errores:string="";

  id = 0;
  paramsSubscription: Subscription;


  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
           private router: Router,
           public strapiserv:StrapiService
    ){ 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.strapiserv.getData().subscribe(res=>{

        this.datas= res as string[];

    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
        if(error.status == 0){
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+" \n Ha ocurrido un error del lado del cliente o un error de red.";
        }else{
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+"\n\n"+error.statusText;
        }
    })


  this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.data = this.strapiserv.getItemFromAllItems( params['id'] );
    });


  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.paramsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

And here is my service 'strapi.service.ts' in which I may have to create a method correctly 'getItem()', but I am not sure.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StrapiService {

  REST_API: string ='http://localhost:1337/articles';
  //https://strapi-dot-gmal-api-313723.uc.r.appspot.com/
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  getData():Observable<any>{

    let API=this.REST_API;
    return this.httpClient.get(API,{headers:this.httpHeaders}) .pipe(
      map((data:any) => { 
      
        return data;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
    
  }



 getItemFromAllItems(idx: number): Observable<any> {
   return this.getData().pipe(
      // we return the index of the data for this method
      map(data => data[idx])
   );
  }
 
 
}
```

Comment: Hi Luis. Do you need to make a new request to your API according to the ID that was passed to the service, or do you already have all the data that you need in your datas array at your component .ts?

Comment: Hello Vitor!, My datas array have all the data that I need, including the ID. I guess, I just have to make a request of that specific ID, so the app won`t bring me all the blogs stored.

Comment: These are my Angular routes:            const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
 { path: 'pagina/:id', component: PaginaComponent },
];

Comment: So, to be clear, the Blog component is the main Blog page, And, the pagina component is the link of the Blog selected which shows the complete blog info.

Comment: Hello Vitor, Is it possible for you to check this question I posted?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356723/show-only-relevant-entries-from-strapi-blog-in-angular-10

Comment: Hi Luis, sorry for not helping you that fast, I'm currently in a hurry this year-end. But be sure that there is always going to be someone at the SO to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Like Vitor said, maybe you need a new request in your backend that accepts an id and then you can just make an HTTP call to that like so (getItem is if you make a new route in your backend, getItemFromAllItems is if you can't/don't want to make this new route):

```
getData():Observable<any>{

    let API=this.REST_API;
    return this.httpClient.get(API,{headers:this.httpHeaders}).pipe(
      // get rid of all of these (map and catchError), they are doing nothing.
      // Get rid of the `.pipe( )` as well.
      // The map is just returning what it's getting.
      // The catchError is throwing the error it is catching (not needed).
      /* map((data:any) => { 
      
        return data;
      }), 
      catchError( error => {
        return throwError(error);
      }) */
    )
    
  }

 // if your API will have a new route
 getItem( idx:number ): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get(`${this.REST_API}${idx}`);
 }

 // if you don't want to create the new route (can't)
 getItemFromAllItems(idx: number): Observable<any> {
   return this.getData().pipe(
      // we return the index of the data for this method
      map(data => data[idx])
   );
 }
```

Edit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   // having a subscribe within a subscribe is an RxJS antipattern.
   // use the snippet I show below
   this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.data = this.strapiserv.getItemFromAllItems( params['id'] 
      ).subscribe(data => {
     this.data = data;
     console.log(data);
  });
});

  // This one is much better - using switchMap
  this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    // go from params observable to API call observable (you will have to import switchMap)
    switchMap(params => this.strapiserv.getItemFromAllItems( Number(params['id']) ),
  ).subscribe(data => {
     this.data = data;
     console.log(data);
   });


  }
```

Comment: Hello AliF50!, My datas array have all the data that I need, including the ID. I guess, I just have to make a request of that specific ID, so the app won`t bring me all the blogs stored.

Comment: Since I am a newbie in Angular, I would like to show you my Angular routes.  const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
 { path: 'pagina/:id', component: PaginaComponent },
];

Comment: So, to be clear, the Blog component is the main Blog page, And, the pagina component is the link of the Blog selected which shows the complete blog info.

Comment: Hey Luis, okay no problem. With regards to your route, I think you can read the `id` from the route and using that id (converted to a number), you can use `getItem` or `getItemFromAllItems`. Here is how to read params: https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/routeparams.

Comment: Ok!, I will try your advice!!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello AliF50, I added some thing to my code. For instance, I added this to my pagina component:  this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params....... , and in my service I added the function getItemFromAllItems(idx: number). But is still showing all the blogs in the detail page. Also, I update the code on this post

Comment: Check out my edit. In RxJS, you have to `subscribe` to the observable in order for it to "take flight". The first snippet is not that great (subscribe within a subscribe). The second snippet is much better. If you don't subscribe, nothing happens.

Comment: Hello AliF50, In the switchMap snippet, you wrote 'pipe', after the word 'params'.  But It seems that the code only recognizes the word 'subscribe' after the word 'params'.  Are you sure you can write 'pipe' in that line of code?:  this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe

Comment: Yes, if it is an observable it should be able to be piped.

Comment: I am having a similar problem and after I implemented everything here and tried ```console.log(data)```, I get ```undefined```

Comment: @Sammy, Sorry, I am not sure what the issue can be.