# Show only relevant entries from a Blog in Angular 10 with ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, strapi

I have a Blog backend made with Strapi, where you can add some content-types like title field, description field and content field. I also have a boolean content-type to set if the blog is relevant or not. I set an ngFor in Angular to show all my blog entries; But I just want to show the relevant ones. Actually, I am showing the relevant ones using the ngIf directive, but Angular is leaving some white spaces for the non-relevant entries. Is there some way to remove these white spaces?? I guess it must be something with ng-template.

This is my html, where I set my ngFor:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let data of datas; index as i"accesskey="">                                                    
    <div class="banner-wrapper" *ngIf='data?.relevante==True; else relevante'>
        <ng-template #myrelevante></ng-template>
        <a [routerLink]="['/pagina',data.id]" title="Leveling up in CSS">
            <div class="banner-wrapper-content">
                <h1 class="h2">{{ data.title }}</h1>
                <!-- <span class="category-tag category-tag-white"></span> -->
                <h3 class="mylittle">{{ data.description }}</h3>
                <time datetime="2016-01-18" class="">{{ data.fecha | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</time>
            </div>
        </a>
        <img class="img-fluid"
                 src="http://localhost:1337{{ data.image.url }}"
                 alt="foto"
                 width="100%" 
                 data-rjs="2"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

And, this is an image which show the white spaces for the non relevant blog entries:

[image: Blog entries]

I also share my ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StrapiService } from '../../../services/strapi.service';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.scss']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  datas:any=[];
  errores:string="";
  totalLength:any;
  page:number = 1;

  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private meta: Meta,
    public strapiserv:StrapiService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.title.setTitle('Blog');
    this.meta.updateTag({ 
      name: 'description', 
      content: 'Publicaciones más relevantes del mundo cloud, transformación digital y el mundo empresarial' 
    })
    this.meta.updateTag({
      name: 'keywords',
      content: 'Transformacion digital, Cloud, La nube, GCP, trabajo remoto, eSource capital, migración de datos, CSS, 2021, Navent, Google Cloud, Microsoft, Ciberseguridad'
    })


    this.strapiserv.getData().subscribe(res=>{

        this.datas= res as string[];

        this.totalLength = res.length;

    }, error =>{
      console.log(error);
        if(error.status == 0){
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+" \n Ha ocurrido un error del lado del cliente o un error de red.";
        }else{
            this.errores="Código del error: "+error.status+"\n\n"+error.statusText;
        }
    })  


  }


  filterRelevante(datas: Data[]) : Data[] {
      return datas.filter(data => data.relevante)
  }


}
```

Comment: use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#hosting-a-directive-without-a-dom-element), not a div: `<ng-container *ngFor="...">...</ng-container>`. BTW, another aproach is filter your datas: `this.datas=this.datas.filter(x=>x.relevante)`

Comment: Why not just filter the data in your ts file? If you don't want multiple versions of you data write a function that takes your data array and returns it filtered. Then you just wrap the 'data' in your template with that function. Ideally you would get your data as an observable and pipe it to apply filterering, so you can use async pipe on the piped observable in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that takes your data array and returns it filtered.

In your .ts:

```js
filterRelevante(datas: Data[]) : Data[] {
    return datas.filter(data => data.relevante)
}
```

Then you just wrap the 'data' in your template with that function.

In your html:

```html
<div 
    class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"
    *ngFor="let data of filterRelevante(datas); index as i"accesskey="">
```

*I just assumed the type of your data here to be Data, which is probably not the case. It would also be a bad name, but I like to type things in typescript so I recommend to write your own interface for your data and name it properly, instead of just using any.*

Comment: Hello H3AR7B3A7!!,   I am new in Angular and also I added my ts file to this page.  So, I am not sure what the type of my data is. but I have named an array like this: datas:any=[];.  In the code you provide the ' Data[ ] ' word appears underlined in red, as It cannot find the name 'Data'

Comment: Hello again!  I changed the type of data to 'any', and it works well!!!.   Just one thing, it is showing the non-relevant entries instead of the relevant ones. But it is funny since we are filtering the relevants, ja!

Comment: Hello!, I fixed something in my backend!, Yes! it workss!! thanks a lot!!!!